# Recursive Folder/Directory Copy with AS3 /Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to use pause/resume function to this??

```
source.copyTo( destination );
```

It would be great if you can send it at the earliest.

Comment: yes AIR.to copy folders from one location to another ..edited question

Answer (score 5):

I found one solution here [CookBook from Adobe](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Merge_two_directories-12466.html)

```
private function copyInto(directoryToCopy:File, locationCopyingTo:File):void
{
    var directory:Array = directoryToCopy.getDirectoryListing();

    for each (var f:File in directory)
    {
        if (f.isDirectory)
          copyInto(f, locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name));
        else
          f.copyTo(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not copy empty folders?

Comment: nope foreach doesnt get executed for empty directories,, if directory.length = 0 ,just copy directory to copy to location to copy ie. directoryToCopy.copyTo(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(directoryToCopy.name), true);

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use the File.copyTo() method:

```
var source:File = new File();
source.resolvePath( 'sourceFolder' );
var destination:File = new File();
destination.resolvePath( 'destinationFolder' );
source.copyTo( destination );
```

If the directories are large and you don't want your app to be stuck waiting for the copy, you can use copyToAsync, which will cause the source file to dispatch Event.COMPLETE when the job's done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code from above if anyone wants to copy the entire directory; empty folders and all. Notice the "copyEmptyFolders" parameter to be used in the arguments.

```
    //Recursivley copies directory.
    private static function copyInto(directoryToCopy:File, locationCopyingTo:File, copyEmptyFolders:Boolean=true):void
    {

        var directory:Array = directoryToCopy.getDirectoryListing();

        for each (var f:File in directory)
        {
            if (f.isDirectory)
            {

                // Copies a folder whether it is empty or not.
                if( copyEmptyFolders ) f.copyTo(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name), true);

                // Recurse thru folder.
                copyInto(f, locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name));

            }
            else
                f.copyTo(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name), true);

        }

    }
```